# Dialog box close not working in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am opening dialog through

```
    public void openDialogRegionList() {        
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("RegionList");       

}
```

I have a commandLink onClick of that and i need to close dialog box.

```
    public void setId(ActionEvent event){

        UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
        String value = (String) component.getAttributes().get("value");         
        this.regionId = value;              
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog("RegionList");      

}
```

But the dialog box is not closing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Primefaces are you using? I can't find any version of `RequestContext` that has `openDialog` and `closeDialog` methods. Besides that, your question lacks a lot of context. No code showing the dialogs or the naming of your UI components.

Comment: Iam using primefaces 4.0 RegionList is an .xhtml file that gets opened on calling open dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can add `oncomplete="PF('dialogName').close()"` attribute to your html button. Wether it doesn't work, other solution is to call the `hide()` method.